# My exception can't be caught

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception

I can't seem to catch this exception at all and the app just crashes.

```
public void GoToStation(View v)
{
try
{
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomizedListViewStudentZone.class);
 startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
} 

}
catch (Exception e)
{
Toast.makeText(this, "You need a data connection to view Safety Zones", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

}
```

I just keep getting an app crash and Null Pointer Exception

Here is my Log Cat

```
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{police.uk.greatermanchesterpoliceandroid/police.uk.greatermanchesterpoliceandroid.CustomizedListViewStation}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1830)
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at police.uk.greatermanchesterpoliceandroid.CustomizedListViewStation.onCreate(CustomizedListViewStation.java:100)
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post the logcat of the exception

Comment: You need to catch the NPE CustomizedListViewStudentZone.onCreate

Comment: Your error is not in the given code. It is in the activity you are starting. `01-06 04:55:28.667: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at police.uk.greatermanchesterpoliceandroid.CustomizedListViewStation.onCreate(CustomizedListViewStation.java:100)`

Comment: In the code sample you have given above, the catch block should come right after the try block. Your catch block is outside the `GoToStation(View v)` method, which doesn't make much sense. But, from the logcat, this does not look like the source of NPE.

Comment: Show your onCreate line 100

Comment: The exception is not thrown here! It is thrown when the execution goes away from here! Specifically it is thrown when the new activity is created! Check your xml files!

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Gabriel Netto, your error is in `onCreate` of `CustomizedListViewStation`.  The call to `startActivityForResult` just fires off an intent to the android OS and will return right away, hence it will not catch any exceptions thrown by your new activity. Actually, the code you put after `startActivityForResult` may even run before that `onCreate`.  You need to check for errors in `onCreate` of `CustomizedListViewStation`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch such exceptions because of architecture of Android OS. By calling `startActivity` (or similar methods), you're not actually creating new `Activity` right away. Instead, you saying that you **want** to display such `Activity` and OS registers your `Intent` (literally, **intent**) to do so. Then, when OS will decide that it's good time to handle your `Intent` it will create your `Activity`.

In other words - `Activity` will be created not within call to `startActivity`, but later. Within some internal logic of OS. So, when exception is thrown - you're not able to catch it, since it's not in your method anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitry Zaitsev said, you will not handle exceptions of the Activity life-cycle at the startActivity.

Instead, you should capture Exceptions at the onCreate of the second Activity that can throw Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to everyone who answered.  It was indeed fine code to use.  The error was being thrown by the destination activity.

The fix was to handle the error on create of CustomizedListViewStudentZone.

I applied a try catch to this method and the issue was fixed.

Comment: Could you click the checkmark next to the appropriate answer so future readers will see the correct answer? Thanks.